# Add Windows Printer to Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, windows, printing

I have a Windows 7 computer that I am trying to print to from a Mac. I have added my printer using a smb:// protocol and it works and says Idle, however when I try to print I get the following:

Status: On Hold (Authentication required)

Job Message: Session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

I have tried as a guest user and logging in to an account on the computer. It is shared and I can print fine over the network using another Windows computer. The printer will not show up under Windows printers in the add printers dialog (from System Preferences -> Printers). I have also tried as an LPD (yes I did enable it on the Windows side) and that didn't work either.

Comment: Is your printer shared with a homegroup?